# sharepoint 2010 unable to open subwebsites from left navigation menu

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

i am using sharepoint 2010 and making an appliaction 
my problem is that i dont know why my website unable to open the sub website
i have one parent website and two sub website as>
parent EL

1. >hr
2. >Accounts

its able to open hr but when i try to open accounts its prompt on new page showing error message as following

**`an unexpected error occured and showing co relation id.`**

please help me ...thanks in advance

NOTE:this problem started when i started change the theme of my master page before it was working well

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site [here](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=353) to see how to debug correlation Id problems with [uls viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer). If you need any more information, open the viewer ,check the problem and post it here.